# Connection string - Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, database-connection, connection-string

I am using Webmatrix.data's Database entity to create a database connection, however it doesnt like my connection string. I am running it from MVC ASP.net.

Ive tried changing it to server / database, but still errors the same. Where am I going wrong?

```
        using (var db = Database.OpenConnectionString(@"Data Source=MY-HP\Serv;Initial Catalog=MyDBSQL;User ID=sa;Password=password"))
        {
            var items = db.Query("SELECT * FROM TaskPriority");
        }
```

**Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.**

Comment: What database server (SQL Server, MySQL, Postgresql, etc) are you using?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

check here: [Database.OpenConnectionString Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548376%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)

try to specify the provider name as second parameter, from the MSDN example:

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=SmallBakery;Integrated Security=True";

var providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";

var db = Database.OpenConnectionString(connectionString, providerName);
```

Comment: Sniff, i spent 3 hours trying to figure this out. Cheers ma man! Saved me more headache.

Answer (score 17):

ARRRRHHHHHH!!!!!
*This is the second time I've run into this, grrrh - wasted hours on it.*

Error:

**The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog;MyDatabase;data source'.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:**

Stacktrace:

> at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString,
>   SqlCredential credential)

This was my faulty connection string:

`<add name="Production" connectionString="Password=Secret;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUserID;Initial Catalog;MyDatabase;Data Source=aquickborwnfoxjumpedover.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Looks good right? **WRONG**

Eventually I spotted the semi-colon here:

> Initial Catalog;MyDatabase

To correct it, I used an equal sign:

> Initial Catalog=MyDatabase

The correct connection string:

`<add name="ConnString" connectionString="Password=Secret;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUserID;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Data Source=aquickborwnfoxjumpedover.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the error in one of the IdentityServer quickstarts.

Had to replace

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

With

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Using

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Because obviously my DB was a Microsoft SQL Server and not SQLite.

Comment: This turned out to be the case for me... Thank you mate!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the below code

**Config file :**

```
   <connectionStrings>
   <add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"></add>
  </connectionStrings>
```

**cshtmlfile :**

```
var db = Database.Open("con");

var selecteddata = db.Query("select * from movie");
```

Answer (score 4):

For me I was getting this error because I was using a templated solution.  Unbeknownst to me the template only installed support for sqlite.  I had to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and change the calls in my code from `UseSqlite` to `UseSqlServer`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check your connection string.

I received the error because I had db(instead of 'Database') in my connection string.

```
 "DevConnection": "server=DEL1-XX-XXXX;db=DonationDb;user=sa;password=XXXX"
```

Updating the above connection string(**db to Database**) should solve the problem. Below is the working connection string.

```
 "DevConnection":"server=DEL1-XX-XXXX;Database=DonationDb;user=sa;password=QwerXXXX"
```

Comment: I had this same problem when I tried to remove migrations with "donet ef migrations remove". I was implementing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v5.0.4. I got this error because as @Risgu Ranjan mentioned, the connection string was wrong. In my case I had "Initial Catalog" instead of Database. It worked after I changed "Initial Catalog" to Database. Thanks for sharing your idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

---

1. You can check your connection string format clearly especialy " and ". In my case this is:

---

2. You may try generate db by EF again.