# Wrong connection string NHibernate 3.3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, sql-server-2012

How to write correct connection string for Nhibernate using SQL Server 2012?

Should I write also database name?

Error:
I get error with wrong „initial catalog”

Wrong connection string for NHibernate (I copy this connection string from my server):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=RAFAL-KOMPUTER\MSSQLSERVER4;Initial Catalog=rafal;Integrated Security=True</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I copy connection string from this part:
[image]

I am trying also this but does not help.

```
<property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=RAFAL-KOMPUTER\MSSQLSERVER4;Initial Catalog=rafal;Integrated Security=True</property>
```

I don`t know how correct configure for **SQL Server 2012**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first snippet should not work, while the driver is for CE (Compact edition).

The second one looks better, and even more it is working for me. (see more here http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012). The most important thing, is to have correct settings of the Provider name (check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8150792/315850). Try this adjusted snippet (just to be sure that all parts are set correctly)

```
<property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
<!-- to profit from features in 2012, use its dialect -->
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
<!-- the simplest connection string -->
<property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=RAFAL-KOMPUTER\MSSQLSERVER4;Database=rafal;Trusted_Connection=True;</property>
```

We have to be sure that correct driver is used (not CE or any other then `NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver` which means `System.Data.SqlClient`)

Double check that your 1) SQL server and named instance is: `RAFAL-KOMPUTER\MSSQLSERVER4` and 2) the Database name is: `rafal` and 3) your login has access rights to it, this must work

Comment: Now I get this error -> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: As I told you, with your second settings, I was able to run it! So the issue is elsewhere. Maybe the Browser Service is not running, Maybe TCP is not enabled.... Other words. The configuration of NHibernate is right now correct (I would say) and the problem is elsewhere. I suggest, try to search here on SO the "A network related...." Very soon you should get some hints

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391503/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne

Answer (score 0):

just replace : `SqlServerCeDriver` by `SqlClientDriver` as below :

Replace : `<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver</property>`

By: `<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>`