# Exception: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog' when hard coding connection string to dbcontext

Tags: c#

I have hard coded my connection string to the dbcontext of Entity Framework DB first.

```
public MirrorBranchesEntities(string connectionStringName, string db)
        : base(@"name=" + connectionStringName + " connectionString=metadata=res://*/MirrorBranches.csdl|res://*/MirrorBranches.ssdl|res://*/MirrorBranches.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=data source=(local);initial catalog=" + db + ";user id=sa;password=Qwer0987;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework; providerName=System.Data.EntityClient")
    {
    }
```

There are multiple databases that uses that connection string. The problem is that it is returning an exception

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)

**Update**

I have updated my connection string -- took away the double metadata attribute and removed an extra single-quote

I am trying to put the connection string in an `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` but could not insert it in the context.

```
public static MirrorBranchesEntities ConnectToSqlServer(string catalog)
    {
        var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {

            DataSource = "(local)",
            InitialCatalog = catalog,
            PersistSecurityInfo = true,
            IntegratedSecurity = true,
            MultipleActiveResultSets = true,

            UserID = "sa",
            Password = "Qwer0987"
        };

        var entityConnectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Provider = "System.Data.EntityClient",
            ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ConnectionString,
            Metadata = "res://*/MirrorBranches.csdl|res://*/MirrorBranches.ssdl|res://*/MirrorBranches.msl", 

        };

        return new MirrorBranchesEntities(entityConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString, sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog);
    }
```

then I changed my context to `base(ConnectToSqlServer(connectionStringName,db))` but it says invalid arguments.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150737/asp-net-mvc3-connection-string-keyword-not-supported-initial-catalog

Comment: refactoring using ``string.Join(";", `` **...** ``)`` should reduce some complexity

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I'll try that.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman Nope, it didn't work.

Comment: @J.PMasangcay I wasn't a proposed solution, but an advice to break down your long connection string into multiple lines - when applying it accordingly, it is equivalent to your string.

Comment: @J.PMasangcay See my [paste](http://pastebin.com/nJ8MpWJ7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your value. In your example there is doubled `metadata=` expression. Also try to use quotes inside your string:

```
base("name=" + connectionStringName + "connectionString='metadata=res://*/MirrorBranches.csdl|res://*/MirrorBranches.ssdl|res://*/MirrorBranches.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=data source=(local);initial catalog=" + db + ";user id=sa;password=Qwer0987;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'"; providerName=System.Data.EntityClient")
```

Comment: Yeah, I have removed those. But it is still giving me that initial catalog error. I'll update my connection string

Comment: what about additional quotes inside?

Comment: Yup, took those out as well. except those for concatinations

Comment: still without any success?

Comment: None, I even removed "initial" from initial catalog still no success. What do you think?

Comment: anotther thing that i found is that you trying to insert `providerName` argument inside your `connectionString` argument. is that ok for you?

Comment: Actually, that connection string came from the generated connection string when I created the ADO connection entity framework. Since all the databases are the same, I copied the connection string and put it in the dbcontext since that is allowed. Then I made the modifications like removing the quotes and making the name and catalog into variables to be passed through.

Comment: yes, but as I can see in my solution (which is also uses EF) in connection string node i have 3 attributes: `name, connectionString and providerName`. in you example I see that `providerName` attribute is inside your `connectionString` attribute. so in web.config we have `<add name="name" connectionString="metadata=res://*/IdentityModel.csdl|res://*/IdentityModel.ssdl|res://*/IdentityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string='Data Source=&quot;|DataDirectory|\IdentityDatabase.sdf&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Comment: as you can see, `connectionString` and `providerName` are separate attributes. in you string this is a single argument

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98541/discussion-between-j-p-masangcay-and-andrew).