# Xamarin Android System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported : 'ınitial catalog'. error

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, sql-server-2008-r2

Actually I found similar questions about this topic but I cannot solve my problem. when I run this code on Xamarin Android

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sbuild = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
sbuild.DataSource = "servername";
sbuild.InitialCatalog = "databasename";
sbuild.UserID = "user";
sbuild.Password = "password";

   using (SqlConnection connection = new sqlConnection(sbuild.ConnectionString))
   {
      connection.Open();
      ...
   }
```

I got this error

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported : 'ınitial catalog'.

At first I tried a connection string hand made when it failed I changed to SqlConnectionStringBuilder approach for guarantee it. But I got same error. I need to understand what is wrong with my approach. And how can I Fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Mssql Server 2008 R2

Comment: Hi, have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150737/connection-string-keyword-not-supported-initial-catalog)?