# error about passing connection string to DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to pass `data source=(local);initial catalog=xxx;integrated security=false;user id=sa;password=yyy;` to my EFDbContext. What I've done is

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EFDbContext() : base(@"data source=(local);initial catalog=xxx;integrated security=false;userid=sa;password=yyy;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework")
    {
    }
}
```

But it raises an error saying

> “Keyword not supported：‘initial catalog’”

when I run the program. Is it a problem to the format of my connection string?

Comment: Connection string - Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150737/connection-string-keyword-not-supported-initial-catalog

Comment: it should be `Initial Catalog=xxx;` , note that is should be with capitalized letters, i also recommend to use [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @styx it's not about the case of letters, I've tried Initial Catalog too.

Comment: @HoussemRomdhani the constructor of DbContext can't take provider name as an additional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EFDbContext() : base(@"data source=(local);initial catalog=xxx;integrated security=false;userid=sa;password=yyy;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework")
    {
        this.Database.Connection.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
    }
}
```

Comment: this.Database.Connection doesn't have the definition of Provider